# Bluetooth Low Energy Characteristic Value from Byte

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, uuid, ios-bluetooth

Background:

I am following [this tutorial from raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85900/arduino-tutorial-integrating-bluetooth-le-ios-swift) about connecting a bluetooth low energy shield to my project. I am using the Adafruit BLE friend.

Question:

I cannot figure out how to specify the UUID for the BLE friend. Here is a picture of Adafruits information about the characteristics:

[image: Adafruit's documentation on the characteristics]

Here is [the link to the page on Adafruits page](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-adafruit-ble-bluetooth-low-energy-friend/uart-service)

How can I format the characteristic UUID so it is in this style: F38A2C23-BC54-40FC-BED0-60EDDA139F47

Thanks for any help,

Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the CBUUID constants can be created for the Service and Characteristic as follows.

```
let kServiceUART = CBUUID(string: "6E400001-B5A3-F393-­E0A9-­E50E24DCCA9E") // UART Service
let kCharTX      = CBUUID(string: "6E400002-B5A3-F393-­E0A9-­E50E24DCCA9E") // TX Characteristic (Property = Notify)
let kCharRX      = CBUUID(string: "6E400003-B5A3-F393-­E0A9-­E50E24DCCA9E") // RX Characteristic (Property = Write without response)
```

I don't have a BLE Friend available to verify with.

Comment: O I see how you got those. Thank you very much, I will try it out right now.